# Can I write "top-notch scientists" in a presentation

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can I write "top-notch scientists" or is there a better word to describe very professional employees?

Comment: It depends what kind of presentation, and what kind of audience. Note that ***top-notch*** is very colloquial/slangy, so you might be better using something like ***leading*** or *[internationally-] **respected***.

Comment: By what standard are the scientists rated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context is everything.

"top notch" is rather casual, but not wrong.

You could use a synonym: "excellent" "senior" "brilliant" "renowned".

These all mean slightly different things, you must choose which is most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

"**top-notch**" means "**excellent, superb, brilliant, exclusive, outstanding, finest, best**" or "**top-quality, first-rate**".

Based on this you can guess what "**top-notch scientists**" may mean.

I can think of "**top scientists**", "**leading scientists**", "**greatest scientists**", "**outstanding scientists**" for those who are the best of the best.

Comment: "Very professional scientists" would sound like you're trying too hard, as if there is some reason people would suspect they are not professional.  All of the others are fine, though.

Comment: @Andrew There's a slight truth in your words. However, I can't see anything bad in "**very professional**".

Comment: It's not about meaning but nuance.  Since there's no reason to use "**very**", it raises the question of "why?" -- as in "what are you trying to defend?"  It's not uncommon to be suspicious of people who excessively qualify their adjectives without reason -- with some notable exceptions.